# Why does the following "routes" construct work?

Tags: angular

My understanding is that routes are based on a 
"First Match Wins" principle, and therefore the most specific routes should be placed at the beginning of the routes array, and the most general routes should go at the end.

However, in the code below, which works just fine for me, is not the most general route placed at the beginning, and then the next two routes have the more general one first and the more specific second?

1. Why doesn't the first route always match every route (meaning that the other routes never get matched)? I thought the empty path (`path: ''`) matches everything, because all paths begin and end with `''`, but is my understanding on this wrong?
2. Similarly, even assuming we do get past `path:''`, why doesn't `'search/'` always trigger, never allowing `'search/:query'` to be matched? (is this because of `pathMarch: 'full'`?).

Many thanks!

from `app.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    component: HomePageComponent 
  },
  { path: 'search',      
    redirectTo: '/search/angular', 
    pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'search/:query',
    component: GitSearchComponent,
    data: {title: 'Git Search'}
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Crowdpleasr, the principle is applied when you has an argument. imagine some like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'uno/:id', 
    component: HomePageComponent 
  },
  { path: 'uno/search',      
    component: OtherComponent
  }
 ];
```

NOT work because uno/search match with uno/:id (so you never reach OtherComponent)

pathMatch: 'full'  is used in redirect so only "exact" value redirect to the page. (in your case, if you not put, search/angular, search/other and search/another redirect too)

Comment: Many thanks. That makes sense. But what about the `path: ''` case? Doesn't that match with everything, because all paths start and end with `''`?